# How to access Internet address property of an item in the Temporary Internet Files folder

Tags: c#

I know this folder has some trickery associated with it via hidden files and cache.  I'm looking to retrieve the Internet address detail of the file that you can see while using windows explorer, but I don't see a way to do it.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  var path = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.InternetCache),"Content.IE5");

  DirectoryInfo dInfo = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Temporary Internet Files");


    DoStuff(dInfo);

    Console.ReadLine();
}

static void DoStuff(DirectoryInfo directory)
{
     FileInfo[] taskFiles = directory.GetFiles("RM0000*");//file name starts with RM0000

    foreach (System.IO.FileInfo fi in taskFiles)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}: ", fi.Name, fi.CreationTime); //This part is where I looked for the address details, but there is no option to display that property. 
    }
```

Is there a way to retrieve the Internet address info for each file in the Temporary Internet Files folder?

Comment: I think it's something to do with INTERNET_CACHE_ENTRY_INFO 
       GetUrlCacheEntryInfo( string url ) but I'm not sure how to incoporate that in my script.